# $A$ and $B$ are matrices representing the same linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$V$ is a two dimensional vector space and $\zeta:V\to V$ is a linear map. $A$ is a matrix of $\zeta$ with respect to the basis $\{a,a'\}$ and $B$ is its matrix with respect to the basis $\{b,b'\}$

If $A$ and $B$ are matrices representing the same linear transformation, does this mean that:

$M(T,\{a,a'\}, \{b,b'\}) A = M(T,\{a,a'\}, \{b,b'\}) B$

Where $M$ is the matrix of transformation(T) from the first basis to the second.

Comment: Leave me a comment anywhere where I can see it and it will send me a notification, I have something for ya

Comment: @AlecTeal Hi ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap the order on one side of the $=$. If you have a vector in the $a$-basis, transforming that via $A$, and then change basis would be signified by $M_TA$, while first changing basis and then transforming via $B$ would be $BM_T$. Those are the ones that are equal, and they both express the transformed vector in the $b$-basis.

Comment: Where your $M_T$ standards for the transformation matrix?(As opposed to transposed or something else)

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge No, that's just me taking liberties because I'm writing on my phone. I think my book usually just used $B$ as a change-of-basis matrix. But yes, it signifies the cange-of-basis matrix (from $a$ to $b$) in my answer.

Comment: I think I am confused by the fact that both sides put us in the basis $\{b,b'\}$. You are saying that the correct interpretation is:

$$M(T,\{a,a'\},\{b,b'\})\times A = B \times M(T,\{a,a'\},\{b,b'\})$$ correct? and that either side is a matrix with the basis $\{b,b'\}$

Comment: @Comittingtoachallenge that is the equality I had in mind. Both sides is a matrix that when multiplied with a vector in the $\{a,a'\}$ basis, results in the transformed vector in the $\{b,b'\}$ basis.